# Растянуть шапку

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно меню растянуть на всю ширину экрана,как можно это сделать?
Знакомый сказал,что верстка кривая,и нужно враппер поменять местами с контентом.
Но хотелось бы узнать по-подробнее.Так как ковырял.но ничего не получилось.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам [сайт](http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/)

Comment: Рекомендую привести здесь пример кода. Так на вскидку могу предложить велосипед, добавьте `#navigation` стили `width: 107.5%; margin-left: -4%;`.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk Кода чего?
Ссылка на сайт же присутствует

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так.

```css
/* убери отступы всей страницы */

body {
  padding: 0;
}
/* добавляй только там где нужно */

.headerInfo,
.content {
  padding: 0, 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Пример страницы</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="headerInfo">
      <!--Твое изображение с текстом-->
    </div>
    <nav>
      <!--Навигация-->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <!--Контент сайта-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Уже нашел костыль,благодарю за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Костыль но все же. Добавляем style.css код

```
#navigation {
    width: calc(100% - (-99px));
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

а в layout.css на 75 строке поменять это

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    ul.nav li {
        padding-left: 3%;
    }
}
```

на это

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    ul.nav li {
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 10000000000000000000000000000px;
left:0px;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]